# How to give id to post in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make this structure in my Cloud Firestore of a Post:
I want to make this structure in my Cloud Firestore of a Post:

```
 Users
   |
   |-> UserId
           |
           |-> OneUserPosts
                   |
                   |->PostId
                         |
                         |-> PostContent
                             Comment 1
                             Comment 2
```

Below is the activity where i want to create a post:
How can i give id to my post ?

```
  public class Add_Post extends AppCompatActivity {
         EditText posttext;
     FirebaseUser user;
 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add__post);
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        try {
            actionBar.setTitle("Write Your Post");

        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }catch (NullPointerException e){}
        posttext = findViewById(R.id.PostTextTextMultiLine);
  }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.addpostmenu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.POST:

    savepost();

                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void savepost() {
        String Post = posttext.getText().toString();

        if (Post.length()<5){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter at least 10 words ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        else{
         try {

            CollectionReference postref = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                    .collection("Users").document(user.getUid()).collection("OneUserPost");
            postref.add(new posttextlist(Post));
            Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully Posted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
}catch (NullPointerException e){}
        }


    }

}
```

Please solve my problem. I searched everywhere but i didn't get answer.
Please solve my problem. I searched everywhere but i didn't get answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using the following line of code:

```
postref.add(new posttextlist(Post));
```

CollectionReference's [add(Object data)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference#add(java.lang.Object)):

> Adds a new document to this collection with the specified data, assigning it a document ID automatically.

If don't need this behavior, then you should use DocumentReference's [set(Object data)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#set(java.lang.Object)):

> Overwrites the document referred to by this DocumentReference.

So your code should like this:

```
CollectionReference postref = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("Users").document(user.getUid())
                .collection("OneUserPost");
String id = postref.getId(); //Do what you need to do with this id
postref.document(id).set(new posttextlist(Post));
```

Comment: It is not storing data in cloud firestore.

Comment: "It is not storing data in cloud firestore" isn't enough information to see what is wrong. Do you have any errors? Have you attached a listener to see if something is wrong when the Task is not successful?

Comment: It is not showing any error. It shows toast. But not storing data.

Comment: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Comment: In that case, please set your Security rules to allow the write operation.

Comment: Be sure to add it to Cloud Firestore. If the rules were correctly added, that error of "Missing or insufficient permissions" would not have appeared. Please edit your question and add the rules you have now.